# Very strange: how to find hanging code in Laravel Controller?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, rate-limiting

I'm administering a website built in Laravel, which on some servers sometimes hangs for exactly 30 seconds or multiples of that (60, 90, 120 or even 150 seconds). The "30 second bug" (as it is called internally here) can be replicated fairly easy by simply doing some ajax calls many times very quickly. It happens to other calls as well, but using this call it's more easy replicate and isolate to one call.

The fact that it are always multiples of 30 seconds made me think that the bug is some kind of rate limiter which hits when many requests are made very fast. But my research told me otherwise.

To research this I started by added some log statements in the laravel `public/index.php` file so that the file looks like this (without comments):

```
<?php
syslog(1, "# 1");
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
syslog(1, "## 2");
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';
syslog(1, "### 3");
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
syslog(1, "#### 4");
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
syslog(1, "##### 5");
$response->send();
syslog(1, "###### 6");
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
syslog(1, "####### 7");
```

What I see is that it either hangs at

```
$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);
```

or at

```
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

This already seems very strange to me. Why would it sometimes hang at one point, and other times at another point?

The route which is used is defined as follows in the `routes/web.php` file:

```
Route::post('/ajax', 'DashboardController@ajax')->name('dashboard.ajax');
```

To proceed finding the specific piece of code at which it hangs in the first option (`$response = $kernel->handle( etc..`) I also placed some syslogs in the controller file which is used: `app/Http/Controllers/DashboardController.php`. In there I placed some syslogs in the constructor:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
syslog(1, '- CONSTRUCT 1');
        $this->middleware('auth');
syslog(1, '-- CONSTRUCT 2');
        $this->middleware('permission:' . Permission::getDashboardPermissions('view'));
syslog(1, '--- CONSTRUCT 3');
    }
```

and in the controller function.

```
    public function ajax(Request $request)
    {
syslog(1, '= AJAX 1');
        $action = $request->input('action');
syslog(1, '== AJAX 2');
        $allowed_actions = ['getConsentData', 'getEPDDetails'];
syslog(1, '=== AJAX 3');
        if (in_array($action, $allowed_actions)) {
syslog(1, '==== AJAX 4');
            return response($this->$action(), 200)->header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        }
syslog(1, '===== AJAX 5');

        return false;
    }
```

And here I find something really strange. I see the following in the syslog:

```
# 1
## 2
### 3
#### 4
- CONSTRUCT 1
-- CONSTRUCT 2
--- CONSTRUCT 3
```

It the hangs for the 30 seconds. And only after the 30 seconds, it proceeds with the controller function by showing `= AJAX 1`.

And here I'm stuck. How can it hang between the constructor and the `ajax()` function? I thought nothing would happen in between, but it somehow does. Could any brighter soul than me shed some light on this issue? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]

I can only reproduce this bug on servers which we have with one specific hosting company. I tried reproducing the bug on a simple DigitalOcean VM, but I couldn't reproduce it there. Our setup (both at our hosting company and at DigitalOcean) are Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache in front of it. If you need any more info about this let me know.

Comment: What s your server setup? Can you reproduce in another enviroment? I run some projects on IIS and have experienced some freeze from time to time roughly 10 seconds in my case

Comment: Between `ajax` and controller exists `middlewares` you can look there https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware

Comment: @Anders - The bug only appears with one hosting company. We're on Ubuntu 16.04 with Apache. I've added some more details to the end of the question. Does that tell you anything?

Comment: What about the max_execution_time on both servers?

Comment: @ChinLeung - However long it takes, it always ends in a 200. Whereas if the `max_execution_time` would have hit, it would have ended in a timeout error.

Comment: @yrv16 - But the middlewares are all run from the constructor, and the constructor ends succesfully before the 30 second wait starts. Or am I missing some middleware?

Comment: Does all your requests in end a 200? Or only the last one though?

Comment: @ChinLeung - All of them end succesfully. However long it waits, it _always_ ends in a 200 response.

Comment: There are global middlewares `app/Http/Kernel.php ` and they can be in your route file.

Comment: @kramer65 - I know this was so long ago - but I am having this EXACT same issue. Did you ever find a resolution?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I seemed to have finally nailed down the issue. The storage/framework/sessions folder had over 220,000 files in it! I cleared all these out and now everything seems fine. I have also amended the the session timeout to stop this happening again.

Update:

The session files weren't being overwritten, new ones were being created. Commenting out SessionStart::class from $middleware seems to have solved this issue (left it alone in $middlewareGroups)

```
<?php

namespace App\Http;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel as HttpKernel;

class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{

    /**
     * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
     *
     * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middleware = [
        // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,  <------ commented this out
        // \App\Http\Middleware\TrustHosts::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies::class,
        \Fruitcake\Cors\HandleCors::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
        \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            // \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            // \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
            'throttle:api',
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];

    /**
     * The application's route middleware.
     *
     * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'cache.headers' => \Illuminate\Http\Middleware\SetCacheHeaders::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'password.confirm' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\RequirePassword::class,
        'signed' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ValidateSignature::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'verified' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified::class,
        'checkPermission' => \App\Http\Middleware\CheckPermission::class,
    ];
}
```